# Getting NoReverseMatch at /blog/ at the book django by example

Tags: django

The ERROR :

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'post_detail' with arguments '(2018, 11, 6, 'another post')' not found. 
1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog\\/(?P<year>[0-9]+)\\/(?P<month>[0-9]+)\\/(?P<day>[0-9]+)\\/(?P<post>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\/$']
```

Here is my templates/blog/base.html file:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link href="{% static "css/blog.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>

    <div id="sidebar">
        <h2>My blog</h2>
        <p>This is my blog</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my templates/blog/post/list.html file:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block title %}My Blog{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>My Blog</h1>
    {% for post in posts%}
        <h2>
            <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">
                {{ post.title }}
            </a>
        </h2>
        <p class="date">
            Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}
        </p>
        {{ post.body|truncatewords:30|linebreaks }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

And the blog/urls file:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
    #post views
    path('',views.post_list,name='post_list'),
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:post>/',
         views.post_detail,
         name='post_detail'),
]
```

The blog/views file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from .models import Post

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.published.all()
    return render(request,'blog/post/list.html',{'posts':posts})

def post_detail(request,year,month,day,post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,slug=post,
                                  status='published',
                                  published__year=year,
                                  published__month=month,
                                  published__day = day)
    return render(request,'blog/post/detail.html',{'post':post})
```

Please help me solve the problem, i would be very happy because i been stuck in this for a week!

Comment: The problem is in `get_absolute_url` method, show your `models.py` code.

Comment: Well, the underlying problem is that you have a space in whatever you are passing as the slug argument, but Statevg is right that we need to see the model including the get_absolute_url method in order to help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you pointed that you use `Django by example` book then your `get_absolute_url` is:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('blog:post_detail',
                   args=[self.publish.year,
                         self.publish.month,
                         self.publish.day,
                         self.slug])
```

There's an example how to create `Post` object in book:
[image]

You made a mistype and instead of `slug='another-post'` entered `slug='another post'`.

What is `slug`. From Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#path-converters):

> **slug** - Matches any slug string consisting of ASCII letters or numbers,
>   plus the hyphen and underscore characters. For example,
>   *building-your-1st-django-site*.

As you see, spaces are not allowed in slug.

You can delete your post with incorrect slug and create another object.

Or you can fix existing post directly in shell:

```
from django.utils.text import slugify

post = Post.objects.get(pk=id_of_your_post) # replace with int number
fixed_slug = slugify(post.slug)
post.slug = fixed_slug
post.save()
```

Comment: Thank guy! how did you know that, amazing! I'm very happy now lalalala